# PhpStorm trigger IDE functions with Node.js?

Tags: node.js, phpstorm, gulp

In PhpStorm I use Gulp task runner for some automation purposes. (SASS transpilers, JS minifiers). I use Gulp's watcher instead of IDE's file watcher feature. Because it is easier to configure and very suitable for multi/complex tasks.

But after my tasks completed and my files created/changed, PhpStorm doesn't recognize file changes. And even if my "Deployment Options" are set to "Upload external changes" it doesn't upload anything. Is it possible to trigger some IDE functions like "path refreshing, or uploading directly" with the help of NodeJS. 
Or at least how can I solve upload problem only.

Comment: PHPStorm integrates nicely with Grunt, maybe that would be a nice replacement for Gulp?

Answer (score 1):

please vote for [WEB-14873](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-14873). You can try configuring Gulp as a file watcher in PHPStorm to work out the problem:

```
Program: path/to/node
Arguments: path/to/node_modules/gulp/bin/gulp.js --gulpfile $ProjectFileDir$/gulpfile.js task_name 
Output paths to refresh: path/to/gulp/output
```